# Maximum of a List (possibly with varying length for each index) and a number

Tags: python, neural-network, numpy

Suppose I have a list of length 3. And the entries in the list has dimensions: 5, (5,5), 5
An example can be [[1,23,3,3,2],
[[1,2,2,3,4],[1,4,3,1,4],[6,7,8,5,4],[3,5,2,2,1],[5,2,6,7,8]],
[1,3,6,4,2]]

I want to get the maximum of the list and 5(say). But I want the output of the same dimension as my list.
The idea is used in neural networks. The list can be considered as the weights of the edges in the layers.

I tried to use `np.maximum()` but it needs vectors of the same length/dimension.

In MatLab, the max function returns the list of the same dimension, but I can't find a similar function for python.

Edit- The following is the output I want and the output in MatLab
[image]

Comment: please share the output you want, the one you are getting from matlab.

Comment: @KritiPawar I included the desired output. It's just comparing every element with a number and returning the maximum of each element and the number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def my_max(lst, s = 5):
    try:
        lst = sum(lst, [])
    except:
        pass
        
    return [max(c, s) for c in lst]
```

Let's test it

```
my_max(l[1], 5)
```

returns

```
[5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Comment: It works. Thanks!
I was getting an error because of the way my list was defined. So, if the list is defined as [1,2,3], then it returns []. However, if the list is [[1],[2],[3]], then it works perfectly.